# Where should I place "only" in this sentence?

Tags: adverb-placement

I have three sentences that I am still not clear about. Are they correct or okay to use?

> 1. Only will be send BILL and other documents after 100% payment has been completed.
> 2. BILL and other documents will be send after 100% payment has been completed.
> 3. Only BILL and other documents will be send after 100% payment has been completed.

Which one is okay to go for? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: *send* is incorrect, will+be+past participle i.e. 'sent'. And your sentence 2 misses 'only' -the word in concern!

Comment: Why would you not send the bill until after payment is 100% complete?  Normally, the bill is used to communicate how much payment is needed.  Are you sure _bill_ is the correct word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the above. the correct answer is:

> The **bill** and other documents **will be sent** only after 100% payment has been completed.

Alternatively:

> Only after 100% payment has been completed **will** the **bill** and other documents **be sent**.

3 might be correct in a different context - one that requires other documents e.g.:

> The receipt will be sent immediately. Only (the) **bill** and other documents **will be sent (send)** after 100% payment has been completed.